# Centering responsive website using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i center a page like the below link with navbar down and layout at center in bootstrap 3 (asp.net mvc project)

[[http://everthemes.com/demo/sellegance1/index.php?route=account/register]](http://everthemes.com/demo/sellegance1/index.php?route=account/register%5d)

```
 <div class="container center-block">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bgnav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             <a class="brand" href="index.html"> </a>


        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="footer">
         <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - dum.Inc</p>
    </footer>
        </div>
</div>
```

above not working

Comment: Tried `margin:auto 0px` on your `.container`?

Comment: Your problem is hard to follow, are you able to create a demo page - perhaps on jsFiddle or another such site?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/oVo8zfiVkS added i want navbar looklike above provide url navbar

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net & MVC shouldn't really change how you use Bootstrap.

In CSS (Bootstrap is mostly a css template), you can:
* Center text within a block - bootstrap uses the "text-center" class for this
* Center the block itself - bootstrap uses the "center-block" class for this

It sounds like you want to center blocks, so the second would apply.

Also make sure you use "container" not "container-fluid" if you want a gutter on the left and the right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.container`nested in code. must use only one `container` and use `.row` for multiple nested column.